# Trying to initialise multiple components of type event-set fails, following Building with Components Tutorial

Tags: aframe

I'm following the A-Frame Building with Components tutorial.

First, there is a typo around the Layout Component part:

```
layout="layout: line;
```

should be:

```
layout="type: line;
```

Secondly, I've got to the [Event-Set Component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/guides/building-with-components.html#event-set-component) part. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following errors:

```
core:schema:warn Unknown property `src` for component/system `undefined`
```

and

```
Error: Trying to initialize multiple components of type `event-set`. There can only be one component of this type per entity.
```

The first seems to link to an innocous part of my Browserified code and second is particularly ironic as the tutorial itself states:

> Notice that the event-set component can have multiple instances

The code itself is on my GitHub for the project, and can be seen running via GitHub pages [here](https://jgl.github.io/APieceOfArtAsBigAsIndia/firstIndianPanoramas.html). I would have linked to more pages and my GitHub, but I can only place two links in this post with my newbie status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a more current version of the component. You can grab it from https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/event-set/dist

Comment: Was installing kframe via NPM a mistake? I only installed it three days ago - surely that would have included the updated event-set above? I want to be able to avoid this in the future. Should I use npm update in my project folder to update my installed packages?

Comment: I can bump it now to make sure.

Comment: I just did npm update in my project folder and it didn't seem to do anything kframe related.

I saw that you bumped your version of K-Frame to 0.3.2 but this doesn't have seem to have been picked up by NPM. I bumped my package.json to 0.3.2 or above:

`"kframe": "^0.3.2",`

But that resulted in the following error from NPM:

`npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: kframe@'>=0.3.2 <0.4.0'`

Is this an automated step or do you have to notify NPM? I've edited my blog post [here](http://joelgethinlewis.com/2016/11/04/new-panoramas-from-india/) to reflect my steps.

Comment: I've got the [page working now](https://jgl.github.io/APieceOfArtAsBigAsIndia/firstIndianPanoramas.html), but it would be great to get clarity on whether I should be installing kframe or k-frame via NPM.